# How to login the user to an external page and redirect the user there?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, authentication, cookies

I'm currently trying to find a way to redirect the user to an external protected page, for example foo.com/dashboard. I have the user login credentials and auth cookie for the page. So my question is that how I can redirect the user to that page already logged in, so the user doesn't have to login, I do the login? I will have to add an Cookie header to the request, but it isn't possible with html.

For example, my website is `bar.com` and I have the users auth cookie to `foo.com`.

i want to be able to redirect the user to the dashboard

`<a href="foo.com/dashboard">dashboard</a>`, but it's not possible to add a header to a html link.

Answer (score 1):

> I have the user login credentials and auth cookie for the page. So my question is that how I can redirect the user to that page already logged in

In general, you can't.

There is no way to set cookies for a different origin. That would be a major security problem.

It **might** be possible to submit the login credentials to the login mechanism on the other site, but that would depend on the site supporting a login mechanism that allowed it (e.g. a form submission) and not doing anything that would prevent it (such as CSRF defences or a CAPTCHA).

Directing them to a specific page there would require support for that (e.g. the login form supporting a "go to page X after login" parameter).

Comment: Is it possible to scrape the website?